# Having trouble removing white bar at bottom of hero image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a hero image for a website, and I'm receiving a random white bar the bottom of my website.
This is the HTML

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
  <img src='https://static.pexels.com/photos/158607/cairn-fog-mystical-background-158607.jpeg' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`img` element is by default `display:inline-block; vertical-align:baseline;`

That baseline alignment is what you see.

So either `display:block;` or `vertical-align:top;`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <img style="display:block" src='https://static.pexels.com/photos/158607/cairn-fog-mystical-background-158607.jpeg'/>
</body>
</html
```

Another option - to set your image to background:

```css
    body {
      background: no-repeat url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/158607/cairn-fog-mystical-background-158607.jpeg);
      background-size:cover;
    }
```

```html
    <body>test</body>
```